# Migrating string column into array column django postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

In my models I have old field `tag` and created new one `tags`.

```
class YOUR_MODEL():
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None, db_index=True, choices=[(tag, tag) for tag in TAGS])
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=[(tag, tag) for tag in TAGS]), db_index=True, null=True)
```

Column `tag` have only strings, for example 'APPLE' or 'PEAR'.
I want that column `tags` to be an array of one string after migrations.

Also:

```
TAGS = field_types.FORM_FIELD_TAGS
FORM_FIELD_TAGS = [
    FORM_FIELD_APPLE_TAG,
    FORM_FIELD_PEAR_TAG,
]
FORM_FIELD_APPLE_TAG = 'APPLE'
FORM_FIELD_PEAR_TAG = 'PEAR'
```

In my migrations after creating new field and before deleting old one I want to transfer data from column `tag` into `tags`. I tried using raw sql: `cursor.execute("UPDATE form_builder_formfield SET tags = ARRAY[tag] WHERE tag IS NOT NULL")` but this is not working.

I recived errors:
`django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: "["APPLE"]"`
`"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

I also tried using django queryset but I always end with this errors above. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your migration a RunPython operation. Make a migration, that has 2 operation: adds a new field `tags` and removes old `tag`. Between them add a operation bellow:

```
migrations.RunPython(migrate_tag_data, reverse_code=reverse_tags),
```

You can make `migrate_tag_data` however you like, but I suggest code bellow. Just put it at start of migration file.

```
def migrate_tag_data(apps, schema_editor):
    YOUR_MODEL = apps.get_model("YOUR_APP", "YOUR_MODEL")
    for instance in YOUR_MODEL.objects.all():
        instance.tags = [instance.tag]
        instance.save()


def reverse_tags(apps, schema_editor):
    YOUR_MODEL = apps.get_model("YOUR_APP", "YOUR_MODEL")
    for instance in YOUR_MODEL.objects.all():
        instance.tag = next(instance.tags, None)
        instance.save()
```

Then migrate and you're good!

Comment: Ok. Since I have a lot of records instead .objects.all() I used .objects.filter(tag__isnull=False) so the reords number to change is lower. When I ran migrations same error with '[' occurred.

Comment: Maybe your tags have quotes that prevent SQL query to execute. Mb try changing `instance.tags = [instance.tag]` to `instance.tags = [instance.tag.replace('"', '')]`

Comment: I tried it and result is the same. Also edited my question to show how `TAGS` look like.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I found a solution. Code was all right. The problem was elsewhere. I had a trigger on a database that was changing '{' curly braces into '[' square braces. So even if I explicitly typed '{' into code it anyway changed it to '[', so postgres couldn't create an array.

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to drop down to Python migrations to pull this off. You can do so directly in SQL and still keep it reversible and keep your data. Here's a mostly ready-to-go answer.

The values you want to substitute are:

`MY_MODEL_NAME`: The model name, typically all lowercase and with no app name prepended

`MY_COL_NAME`: The name of the column you're migrating to be an array

`TEMP_COL_NAME`: A temporary column for holding table data during the migration. It can be anything.

`MY_TABLE_NAME`: The full name of your table in the database

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name=MY_MODEL_NAME,
        name=TEMP_COL_NAME,
        field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(
            base_field=models.CharField(max_length=255), default=list, size=None
        ),
    ),
    migrations.RunSQL(
        sql='update MY_TABLE_NAME set TEMP_COL_NAME = array[MY_COL_NAME]',
        reverse_sql='update MY_TABLE_NAME set MY_COL_NAME = (TEMP_COL_NAME)[1]',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name=MY_MODEL_NAME,
        name=MY_COL_NAME,
    ),
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name=MY_MODEL_NAME,
        old_name=TEMP_COL_NAME,
        new_name=MY_COL_NAME,
    )
]
```